# At which stage does SqlBulkCopy check constraints?

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints, sqlbulkcopy

If SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints option is set for SqlBulkCopy insert, does it check the constraints separately after each record, or after all records are inserted?

I have a check constraint that compares some columns to the parent row (through a UDF). I'm using MS Sql Server 2005. The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions.aspx only says "Check constraints while data is being inserted."

In my tests it seems that foreign keys are not checked until the end, but check constraints are checked for each row before adding the next one. This sounds quite odd. I haven't found any documentation about this.

Comment: that UDF will run for each row, and crush performance!

Comment: I would use SQL Profiler to determine the answer.  Perhaps FK's are disabled at the beginning and applied at the end.